# I have an 'm' lonely in all slides of beamer

Tags: beamer, errors, units

I have a problem, I don't know what causes it.
Below are two slides of my presentation in Warsaw theme. In all my slides, there is a `m` appearing.

Other problem, I have to write `100cmm` instead of `100mm` or `10cm` to have my logo fixed in position. Please show the bug. How to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}  
\useinnertheme{default}  
\usepackage{libertine}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{textpos}  
\usetheme{Warsaw}  
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lightgray!40}  
\begin{document}  
    \author{Usulan Penelitian Mandiri}  
    \title[\textit{Title}]{\textbf{Title Displayed\\  
            In the Main First Slide}  
    }  

    \subject{Usulan Penelitian Mandiri \\Tahun 2017}  

    \begin{frame}[plain]  
    \maketitle  
\end{frame}  
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%  
    \begin{textblock*}{100cmm}(.85\textwidth,-1.05cm)  
        \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{LOGO}  
\end{textblock*}}  

\begin{frame}  
\begin{center}  
    \textbf{Tim Pengusul}\\  
    \vspace{0.3cm}  
    Ketua:\\  
    Enos Lolang, S.Si., M.Pd.\\  
    NIDN: 0911056901\\  
    Program Studi Pendidikan Fisika\\  
    \vspace{0.3cm}   
    Anggota:\\   
    Silka, S.Pd., M.Pd.\\  
    NIDN: 0910079001\\  
    Program Studi Pendidikan Fisika\\  
\end{center}  
\frametitle{\textbf{Tim Pengusul}}  
\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: remove the excess `m` in here: `\begin{textblock*}{100cmm}`. it's 100cm, not 100cmm. else remove the excess `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correct the given length for the `textblock` like

```
  \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(.85\textwidth,-1.05cm)  % <================ 100cmm
```

I guess that you want an textblock of 10 cm length which you can get with `10cm` or `100mm` instead the wrong `100cmm`.

Then I get the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}

\useinnertheme{default}

\usepackage{libertine}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{textpos}

\usetheme{Warsaw}  
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lightgray!40}


\begin{document}

\author{Usulan Penelitian Mandiri}  
\title[\textit{Title}]{%
  \textbf{Title Displayed\\  
  In the Main First Slide}  
  }

\subject{Usulan Penelitian Mandiri \\Tahun 2017}  

\begin{frame}[plain]  
  \maketitle  
\end{frame} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%  
  \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(.85\textwidth,-1.05cm)  % <================ 100cmm
    \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{example-image-a}  
  \end{textblock*}%
}  

\begin{frame}  
\begin{center}  
    \textbf{Tim Pengusul}\\  
    \vspace{0.3cm}  
    Ketua:\\  
    Enos Lolang, S.Si., M.Pd.\\  
    NIDN: 0911056901\\  
    Program Studi Pendidikan Fisika\\  
    \vspace{0.3cm}   
    Anggota:\\   
    Silka, S.Pd., M.Pd.\\  
    NIDN: 0910079001\\  
    Program Studi Pendidikan Fisika\\  
\end{center}  
\frametitle{\textbf{Tim Pengusul}}  
\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]